# OpenURL on iphone problem with strings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, openurl, tweak

i am using openURL to open an app with arguments but i get errors when compiling (theos...mobilesubstrate)

Here is my code:
http://pastie.org/private/mg6lbuttin85llxaxwdkw

sorry the code wasn't formating right here ;O
As you can see at the end, i'm trying to open the URL with the argument: "itemIdentifier"

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks :)

here is the error log:
http://pastie.org/2460416

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to make your `app` variable a member variable. I think that by the time you come to use it in the `-(void) open` method, it's nil.

Try something like this:

```
@interface SUItem__HAX : NSObject
{
    long long itemIdentifier;
    NSString *app;
}
```

then in `-(void) setItem` change `NSString* app = appid;` to `app = appID;`

The method to open a link should also read: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string];`

Comment: I modified my answer again. Please don't forget to up-vote and mark an answer as correct if you use it.

Comment: sure, but it still doesn't work :O Here is my code: http://pastie.org/2460601 and here are the errors: http://pastie.org/private/fn0oo4cpvnqfdv5fkkraq

Comment: The error explains that the variable is not in scope. Can you move `NSString *app;` above `@interface` and tell me if that works.

Slightly off topic, can you tell me why there are lots of "%hook" style tags all over the place. What tool are you using to code?

Comment: ok i did what you asked...yay i only have 1 remaining error now :) here is the error: http://pastie.org/2460601 btw, search "mobilesubstrate and theos" on google :)